# How to write Sass for descendants with different ancestors without repeating selectors?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I want the following CSS generated:

```
.productLink .productContainer {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.productLink:hover .productContainer {
  background-color: #f3fbfd !important;
  border: 1px solid #01c1d6;
}
```

I have the following SCSS so far:

```
.productLink
{
  .productContainer
  {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  }

  &:hover .productContainer
  {
    background-color: #f3fbfd !important;
    border: 1px solid $mainColor;
  }
}
```

Is there a way without repeating `.productContainer`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable:

```
.productLink {

    $container: '.productContainer';

    #{$container} {
        // do something
    }

    &:hover #{$container} {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the variable is repeated, so not much cleaner, is it.